# Where do I find the “libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)” and “xdg-utils” dependneices on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dependencies, xdgutils

I’m using Amazon Linux (cannot change this distro at this time) and trying to install Google Chrome (for purposes of running a Selenium server in headless mode) on our EC2 box.  I am getting the below errors. Does anyone know where I can find the “libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)” and “xdg-utils” dependencies?

```
davea@mydevbox ~$ sudo yum install google-chrome-stable
sudo password for davea: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
* amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amzn-main/latest | 2.1 kB 00:00 
amzn-updates/latest | 2.3 kB 00:00 
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:49.0.2623.112-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xdg-utils for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
Requires: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-49.0.2623.112-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
Requires: xdg-utils
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_35-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk-1.6.0_65-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install libgconf2-4
yum install xdg-utils
```